# LibreOffice Calc: How to open CSV with numbers as text?

Tags: csv, format, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to open a CSV (UTF-8) file with the following content in LibreOffice (4.4.7). Content is:

```
00442523534546234234;asdf
asdf;888234800000000023400000
```

But what I get after the import is:

```
4,42523534546234E+017 asdf 
asdf                  8,882348E+023
```

These are the 'real' values in Calc, i.e. it doesn't help to set the cell format to text. What am I doing wrong here? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must set the column types in the `Text Import` wizard to `Text`

[image]

Comment: Ah, I see! And to enable the dropdown one has to select some columns in the preview area. I have to admit I was a bit blind, however the German translation 'Feldbefehle' for 'Fields' is also a bit confusing - I didn't come to the idea that I have to do something in this section. Thanks, man!